# List of URI prefixes (CURIEs)

Tags: hyperref

I'm writing a document in which i talk about many URIs (inline). To not clutter readability too much, i'd like to define and use [CURIE](https://www.w3.org/TR/curie/)s instead (this is common in the [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) community). So rather than talking about http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog i'd like to talk about [dbr:Dog](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog).

Currently i have some code like this in my preamble:

```
\newcommand{\curiesize}{\small}
\newcommand{\defcurie}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1:##1}}}}%
}
\defcurie{rdf}{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns\#}
\defcurie{rdfs}{http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema\#}
\defcurie{owl}{http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl\#}
\defcurie{dbr}{http://dbpedia.org/resource/}
...
\defcurie{foaf}{http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/}
```

So in the document i can then write something like `\dbr{Dog}` to refer to [dbr:Dog](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog).

As the list above gets longer and longer i'd like to extend the `\defcurie` meta-command to somewhere remember the CURIE prefixes and later print a glossary like listing in the front- or backmatter.

Any recommendations how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling around with this some more, i found a first way to solve this myself by extending the preamble meta-command like this:

```
\newcommand{\usedprefixes}{} % used to store `prefix: & \url{uri} \\` like table rows
\newcommand{\defcurie}[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\usedprefixes\expandafter{\usedprefixes\texttt{#1}: & \begin{small}\url{#2}\end{small} \\[1ex] }
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{{\curiesize \href{#2##1}{\nolinkurl{#1:##1}}}}%
}
```

Then later in the document do something like this:

```
\chapter*{List of URI Prefixes (CURIEs)}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
    \usedprefixes
  \end{tabular}
```

Still interested in better/cooler approaches though.